# Triggering a custom event with attributes from a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dom-events

I have a Firefox extension that modifies the content of the page that the user is looking at. As part of that process the extension needs to trigger a custom event that the extension itself adds to the page source. I am having difficulties passing parameters to that custom event. What am I doing wrong?

Script block inserted into the `head` of the page:

```
document.addEventListener("show-my-overlay", EX_ShowOverlay, false, false, true);

function EX_ShowOverlay(e) {
    alert('Parameter: ' + e.index);
    // ...
}
```

Code in the extension:

```
var event = content.document.createEvent("Events");
event.initEvent("show-my-overlay", true, true);
event['index'] = 123;
content.document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The event gets triggered successfully, but `e.index` is undefined.

I managed to get it working by creating an element on the page and then having the event handler find the element and read its attributes, but it didn't feel elegant. I want to do it without the element.

**EDIT:**

I also tried triggering the event with `CustomEvent`, but it throws an exception in the handler:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('show-my-overlay', { detail: { index: 123 } });
content.document.dispatchEvent(event);

function EX_ShowOverlay(e) {
    alert('Parameter: ' + e.detail.index);
    // ...
}
```

> Permission denied to access property 'detail'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access "expandos" (additional properties defined on a native prototype object) across security boundaries. The security boundary in this case being between the fully privileged chrome (add-on) code and the non-privileged website code.

So you need to pass data using something "standard". The `CustomEvent` stuff would do, however your code is wrong. You have to call the constructor or `initCustomEvent()` correctly:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('show-my-overlay', { detail: { index: 123 } });
content.document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Another alternative is [the `postMessage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage).

Comment: Thanks for that info. The MDN doesn't mention a lot of these caveats. I tried triggering a CustomEvent, but the handler is throwing this exception: Permission denied to access property 'details'. Any way around that?

Comment: I'm going to go with `postMessage`, managed to get that working. `content.window.postMessage(...)` together with `window.addEventListener("message", ...)`

Comment: My previously working CustomEvent code stopped working due to this exact problem. On the content_script side, I correctly init with `new CustomEvent('my-event', {detail: {id: 1}})`. On the page script side, ff errors out with the permission denied error "id": I am NOT allowed to access event.detail.id. Any ideas?

Comment: Solved CustomEvent issue with cloneInto and made a new answer with that info.

Comment: @CharlBotha for FireFox you cannot put an object in `detail`.  You can, however, stringify the object.

Answer (score 13):

OP has solved their problem using `postMessage`. For those of us who actually do have to solve it using `CustomEvent` (being able to specify message types is useful), here's the answer:

Firefox won't allow the page script to access anything in the detail object sent by the content script via `CustomEvent` unless you clone the event detail into the document first using the Firefox-specific `cloneInto()` function.

The following does work over here to send an object from the extension to the page:

```
var clonedDetail = cloneInto({ index: 123 }, document.defaultView);
var event = new CustomEvent('show-my-overlay', { detail: clonedDetail });
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent#Firing_from_privileged_code_to_non-privileged_code) have more detail on `cloneInto`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, that I needed to convert my extension to MV3. No idea what the concept of cloneInto is, bit whatever. My cross-browser line of code is:

if (typeof cloneInto != 'undefined') request = cloneInto(request, document.defaultView); //required for ff

Comment: You stopped me hemorrhaging time on this issue porting a Chrome extension to Firefox. Thank you very much for your clear and concise answer!

Comment: For those coming upon this later. the docs for `cloneInto` have moved to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts#cloneinto