# How to send data from a content script to a web accessible resource?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am using a content script (`content_script.js`) to inject a script (`main.js`) into a webpage.

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
     "run_at": "document_end",
     "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "open_in_tab": true
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "main.js"
  ],
  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage"]
}
```

**content_script.js**:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('main.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function() {
    s.parentNode ? s.parentNode.removeChild(s) : null;
};
```

I have some data stored in `chrome.storage.local` (set in the `options.js` file) that I need to read inside a web accessible resource (`main.js` in this case).

The only solution I found so far is to create a custom event in the content script and listen to it in the `main.js` file like the following

**content_script.js**:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(foo, function(result) {
  var event = new CustomEvent("ExtensionOptionsRead", { detail: result });
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

**main.js**:

```
window.addEventListener("ExtensionOptionsRead", function(event) {
  window.extensionOptions = event.detail
})
```

But this does't work on Firefox as I get `Error: Permission denied to access property xyz`.

Does anyone know another way to send data from a content script to a web accessible resource?

Comment: You need to [clone it into the page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081249).

Comment: it worked! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The document recommends us to use `window.postMessage`. It allows us to send any data acceptable for `JSON.stringify()`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_the_web_page

By the way I couldn't see any `Permission denied` error with these codes:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name":"foo",
  "version":"1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
     "run_at": "document_end",
     "js": ["content_script.js"],
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "main.js"
  ],
  "permissions": ["tabs", "storage"]
}
```

content_script.js:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ foo: { property: true } });

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('main.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function() {
    s.parentNode ? s.parentNode.removeChild(s) : null;

    chrome.storage.local.get({ foo: 0 }, function(result) {
      var event = new CustomEvent("ExtensionOptionsRead", { detail: result });
      window.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
};
```

main.js:

```
window.addEventListener("ExtensionOptionsRead", function(event) {
  window.extensionOptions = event.detail
  console.log('window.extensionOptions ', window.extensionOptions);
});
```

Is there any difference from the real code?

Comment: try to invoke `window.extensionOptions.foo.property` on Firefox and you will see the error..

Comment: Ah, OK, I got it. Then `chrome.storage.local.get({ foo: 0 }, function(result) { window.postMessage(result); })` on the content script and `window.addEventListener("message", function(event) { window.extensionOptions = event.data; })` on injected script is the safest way. It implicitly clones the given message into the receiver's namespace.